# Grasping the basics of in-place operations

Tags: python, python-3.3

So...

```
a = [2,3,4,5]

for x in a:
  x += 1

a = [2,3,4,5]
```

Nada.

but if I ...

```
a[2] += 1
a = [2,3,5,5]
```

Clearly my mind fails to comprehend the basics. `print(x)` returns only the integer within the cell so it should simply add the one automatically for each list cell. What's the solution and what am I not grasping?

Comment: The important thing to understand/remember is that `+=` works differently for mutable and immutable objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand what's happening here, consider these two pieces of code. First:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    x = a[i]
    x += 1
```

Second:

```
for x in a:
    x += 1
```

These two `for` loops do exactly the same thing to `x`. You can see from the first that changing the value of `x` doesn't change `a` at all; the same holds in the second.

As others have noted, a list comprehension is a good way to create a new list with new values:

```
new_a = [x + 1 for x in a]
```

If you don't want to create a new list, you can use the following patterns to alter the original list:

```
for i in range(len(a)):      # this gets the basic idea across
    a[i] += 1

for i, _ in enumerate(a):    # this one uses enumerate() instead of range() 
    a[i] += 1

for i, x in enumerate(a):    # this one is nice for more complex operations
    a[i] = x + 1
```

Comment: Use `xrange` when you don't actually need `range` to write the full list into memory.

Comment: @OregonTrail, well, that depends on whether you're using Python 2 or 3; `range` in Python 3 acts like `xrange`. Either way, the semantics are the same for our purposes.

Comment: Explains why this worked as long I used it to append new values to the lists and not actually modify them.

Comment: @OregonTrail OP has tagged Python 3.3 :)

Answer (score 4):

In this case you are defining a new variable `x`, that references each element of `a` in turn. You cannot modify the `int` that `x` refers to, because `int`s are immutable in Python. When you use the `+=` operator, a new `int` is created and `x` refers to this new `int`, rather than the one in `a`. If you created a `class` that wrapped up an `int`, then you could use your loop as-is because instances of this class would be mutable. (This isn't necessary as Python provides better ways of doing what you want to do)

```
for x in a:
  x += 1
```

What you want to do is generate a new list based on a, and possibly store it back to a.

```
a = [x + 1 for x in a]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to +1 on elements of a list of ints:

```
In [775]: a = [2,3,4,5]

In [776]: b=[i+1 for i in a]
     ...: print b
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Why `for x in a:  x += 1` fails ?

Because `x` is an **immutable** object that couldn't be modified in-place. If `x` is a mutable object, `+=` might work:

```
In [785]: for x in a:
     ...:     x+=[1,2,3] #here x==[] and "+=" does the same thing as list.extend

In [786]: a
Out[786]: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
for x in a:
  x += 1
```

Python simply binds the name `x` with the items from `a` on each iteration. So, in the first iteration `x` will be referring to the item which is in the 0th index of `a`. But when you say

```
x += 1
```

it is equivalent to

```
x = x + 1
```

So, you are adding 1 to the value of x and making `x` refer to the newly created number (result of `x + 1`). That is why the change is not visible in the actual list.

To fix this, you can add 1 to each and every element like this

```
for idx in range(len(a)):
    a[idx] += 1
```

Now the same thing happens but we are replacing the old element at index `i` with the new element.

**Output**

```
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**Note:** But we have to prefer the list comprehension way whenever possible, since it leave the original list altered but constructs a new list based on the old list. So, the same thing can be done like this

```
a = [item + 1 for item in a]
# [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The major difference is that, earlier we were making changes to the same list now we have created a new list and make `a` refer to the newly created list.

Comment: If you want to accomplish this without a list comprehension, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop, you declare a **new** variable `x`,

```
for x in a
```

It's this variable you next adds one to
    x += 1

And then you do nothing with `x`.
You should save the `x`somewhere if you want to use it later on :)

Answer (score 1):

The variable **x** inside the **for** loop is a copy of each cell in the **a** list. If you modify **x** you will not affect **a**.

A more "correct" way to increment each element of a list by one is using a list comprehension:

```
a = [elem + 1 for elem in a]
```

You could also use the `map` function:

```
a = map(lambda x: x + 1, a)
```

Comment: `x` is not a copy of each cell, it's a reference to an immutable type

Comment: yes, my bad. It is not a copy of each object in the list

Answer (score 0):

when you put a[2], you are reffering to the third variable in the array 'a'
because the first element which in your case is 2 is stored at a[0] similarly, 3 at a[1] ,4 at a[2] and 5 at a[3]